# Why break gets me out of 2 loops at once and how to fix it

Tags: c, break

Ok, so the idea of the task I have (I am the student) is to allow user to insert a string of words in this form: num1_num2_num3..._numN. The code should create an array X, give it memory dynamically and then I should fill X with numbers from string user inserted.  Simple as that. Well, in the function `stringuniz()` I thought I had it all figured out but it simply wont work. It gets the first number well but it then stops and I think its because of the break. Break behaves (if I am right) like it breaks the entire code and not just the loop. Do you guys have an idea why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void stringuniz(char *);
int *x;

int main(){

    char s[50];
    int i;

    puts("Unesite string brojeva u formatu br1_br2_...brN: ");
    gets(s);

    stringuniz(s);

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(x)/sizeof(int));i++)
        printf("%d",x[i]);
}

void stringuniz(char *s){

    int duz,c=0,i,j,k=0,m=0;
    char b[10];

    duz=strlen(s);

    for(i=0;i<duz;i++)
        if(s[i]=='_')
            c++;

    x=(int*)malloc((c+1)*sizeof(int));
    if(x==NULL) exit(1);

    for(i=0;i<c+1;i++){
        for(j=m;j<duz;j++){
            if(s[j]!='_'){
                b[k++]=s[j];
                m++;
            }
            else{
                b[k]='\0';
                x[i]=atoi(b);
                k=0;
                m++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: never use `gets`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: `sizeof(x)` is the size of a *pointer* to an int.

Comment: Beacause `sizeof(x)` doesn't return the allocated size (only the size of the pointer), the `sizeof(x)/sizeof(int)` is equal to 1 and only the first number is displayed. Modify your `void stringuniz(char *s)` to `int stringuniz(char *s)` and add `return (c+1);` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
(sizeof(x)/sizeof(int)
```

won't give you the size of the array. `sizeof(x)` is the bytesize of `int*` (likely 4 or 8).
You'll need to remember the size as implied by the number of `_` in the string.

Also you have some off-by-one errors in there and for future reference, you might want to choose more descriptive variable names for code you decide to post publicly.

The code worked for me once I changed it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void stringuniz(char *);
int *x;
int x_size = 0;

int main(){
    char s[50];
    int i;
    puts("Unesite string brojeva u formatu br1_br2_...brN: ");
    fgets(s,50,stdin);
    stringuniz(s);
    for(i=0;i<x_size;i++)
        printf("%d\n",x[i]);
}
void stringuniz(char *s){
    int duz,c=0,i,j,k=0,m=0;
    char b[10];
    duz=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<duz;i++)
        if(s[i]=='_')
            c++;
    x=malloc((c+1)*sizeof(int));
    x_size = c+1;
    if(x==NULL) exit(1);
    for(i=0;i<=c+1;i++){
        for(j=m;j<=duz;j++){
            if(s[j]!='_' && s[j]!='\0'){
                b[k++]=s[j];
                m++;
            }
            else {
                b[k]='\0';
                x[i]=atoi(b);
                k=0;
                m++;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void stringuniz(char *);
int *x;

int main(){
    [...]
}

void stringuniz(char *s){
    [...]
}
```

I don't know why many ppl teach it this way, but there is absolute no use in having `main` somewhere in the middle of a source file, and putting it at the end also allows you to get rid of the forward declarations. So, I would write it this way:

```
int *x;

void stringuniz(char *s){
    [...]
}

int main(){
    [...]
}
```

Then you should start using the space character more.

```
    stringuniz(s);

    for(i=0;i<(sizeof(x)/sizeof(int));i++)
        printf("%d",x[i]);
```

In a comment, alain already pointed out, that `sizeof(x)` will return the size of a pointer. So, you need a different way to figure out the size of the array. One way is to add a variable `size_t x_len;` besides `int * x;`. Also, you should use curley brackets even for one line statements, believe me, not only makes it the code more readable, it also prevents introducing bugs on later changes.

```
    for (i = 0; i < x_len; i++) {
        printf("%d", x[i]);
    }
```

.

```
void stringuniz(char *s){
    int duz,c=0,i,j,k=0,m=0;
    char b[10];
```

`b` will hold the word the user enters. If his word is longer then 9 characters, you get a buffer overflow here.

```
    duz=strlen(s);

    for(i=0;i<duz;i++)
        if(s[i]=='_')
            c++;
```

You are counting the number of words here. So, please use more descriptive names like `num_words` instead of `c`. BTW: This is the `x_len` mentioned above.

```
    x=(int*)malloc((c+1)*sizeof(int));
```

No need to cast return value of `malloc`. Actually it might hide bugs. Also, I would use `sizeof(*x)` instead of `sizeof(int)`, because if you change the type of x, in your statement, you also would have to change the `malloc` call. In my statement, the `malloc` call doesn't need to be touched in any way.

```
    x = malloc((c+1) * sizeof(*x));

    if(x==NULL) exit(1);

    for(i=0;i<c+1;i++){
        for(j=m;j<duz;j++){
            if(s[j]!='_'){
                b[k++]=s[j];
```

You are constantly overwriting b with the next word being read. Since you're not using it anyway, you can just skip this line.

```
                m++;
            }
            else{
                b[k]='\0';
                x[i]=atoi(b);
                k=0;
                m++;
                break;
```

And this `break;` only breaks out of the innermost `for (j`-loop.

```
            }
        }
    }
}
```